# Can I write apps for Ubuntu phones and tablets with Mono?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compatibility, mono, tablet

I just wanted to ask if it will be possible to write apps with C# and .NET via Mono for Ubuntu Tablet and Phone. I could not find anything about this matter.

Since I heard that the version for tablets would just work as the desktop one I would guess the answer would be "Yes you could write apps with C#"

Can someone confirm whether this is true or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official word on this. However if you consider that:

1. C#/mono is available on android
2. C#/mono is available on ios
3. C# is available on windows phone 7 and 8

If ubuntu was to prevent use of c# it would be more restrictive then all its competitors.

There are a few issues to overcome first however, firstly c# binding for QT although available have not been packaged for ubuntu (yet). There is currently a blocking issue on mono for arm in debian which needs sorting out. This shouldn't be a big issue as mono works on IOS and android both of which are arm.

My guess is that ubuntu wont support it, however they also will not prevent it. I fully expect that you will be able to develop using c# for ubuntu phones and tablets.